# How to create and use a new sheet as the "new" `ActiveSheet` VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Each time this macro runs I want it to add a new sheet in the workbook and make the `ActiveSheet` this new sheet. Maybe I need to create a parent workbook and worksheet? Im not really sure. Here is my poor attempt at code.

```
If ActiveSheet.index = Worksheets.Count Then
    Sheets.Add
Else
    ActiveSheet.index = Worksheets.Count
End If
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess so it makes sense, this macro will always be run from the first sheet

Comment: Isn't the new Sheet the active sheet by default?

Comment: and if not, [Activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.activate(method)) it!

Answer (score 2):

Just run `Sheets.Add`.
This will create a new sheet and this new sheet will be the active one.

Answer (score -2):

`Worksheets.Add()` returns a reference to the just-added sheet, so there's no need to rely on `ActiveSheet` here...

Like this:

```vb
Dim ws as worksheet
Dim wb as workbook

set ws = activesheet
Set wb = activesheet.parent

if ws.Index = wb.worksheets.count then
    'add a new sheet and set `ws` as a reference to it
    Set ws = wb.worksheets.add(After:=wb.worksheets(wb.worksheets.count))
end if

'now work with `ws`...
```

Answer (score -3):

Here you have it:

```
Sub test()

If ActiveSheet.Index = Worksheets.Count Then
    Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    
        Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Activate
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Index = Worksheets.Count
    End If

End Sub
```

Just tested, it will add a new sheet and then activate it. Thought it's not o good practice to use activate. I would suggest adding sheets with names and then reference them in code