# Pull data from certain WS and paste to another WS

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Need help with my code please. I want to search all worksheets in a workbook that contain a specific string in its sheet name to copy cell data of a range and paste as values into a different ws. I keep getting Run-Time error '9' subscript out of range. It highlights Set wsSumm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary") as the reasoning. I have a Summary tab so I am unsure why it is giving this error.

What I ultimately need to do is take data from A2 of all BL ws and paste into Column A of Summary ws. Then take A1 of all SL ws and paste into Column B of Summary ws. I would need to paste as values. My sheets are named 1-15 as BL, SL (BL1, SL1, BL2, SL2, BL3, SL3, ect) and a Summary ws. Below is what my Workbook looks like and the Code I am using.

[enter image description here][1]

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro1()

    Dim wsSumm As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim strCol As String
    Dim lngRow As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set wsSumm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary") '<-Sheet name for the data to be concolidated. Change to suit.
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> wsSumm.Name Then
            strCol = IIf(StrConv(Left(ws.Name, 2), vbUpperCase) = "BL", "A", "B")
            lngRow = IIf(StrConv(Left(ws.Name, 2), vbUpperCase) = "BL", 2, 1)
            wsSumm.Range(strCol & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ws.Range("A" & lngRow)
        End If
    Next ws
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")` fails then the workbook where the code is running doesn't have a worksheet with that name.  Have you checked for (eg) a space before/after the name?

Comment: Tim, yes I did. I even tried renaming it. Still getting the error. I was thinking, is there a way to pull the data and put it into a new worksheet named Summary?

Comment: You can use `Worksheets.Add`  to create a new sheet eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68819921/how-to-create-and-use-a-new-sheet-as-the-new-activesheet-vba/68820228#68820228